# Animation Constructor not working in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, paintcomponent

Hello I am new to Java GUI I made a second.java which is as below:

```
package theproject;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class second extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private Timer animator;
private ImageIcon imageArray[];
private int delay=50, totalFrames=8, currentFreames=1;

public second()
{
  imageArray= new ImageIcon[totalFrames];
  System.out.println(imageArray.length);
  for(int i=0; i<imageArray.length;i++)
  {
      imageArray[i]=new ImageIcon(i+1+".png");
      System.out.println(i+1);

  }
  animator= new Timer(delay, this);
  animator.start();

   }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g )
  {
  super.paintComponent(g);
   if(currentFreames<8)
   {

  imageArray[currentFreames].paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
  currentFreames++;
  System.out.println(currentFreames);
}
else{
    currentFreames=0;
}
  }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    repaint();
}

 }
```

And a Gui calling the constructor second and output is not showing . Can you please guide me what should I do and the gui is given below:

```
   package theproject;

 import java.awt.EventQueue;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;

  public class Sav {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Sav window = new Sav();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Sav() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(10, 0, 261, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        second s= new second();
         frame.add(s);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(273, -1, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

}
}
```

The gui has to basically call the constructor and which will showcase the animation on the screen If someone what i am doing wrong or if something that has to be done please let me know .

Answer (score 1):

First, don't update the state within the `paintComponent` method, paint can occur for a number of reasons at any time, mostly without your interaction. Painting should simple paint the current state.  In your `ActionListener`, you should advance the frame and make decisions about what should occur (like resetting the frame value)

Second, you never actually add `second` to anything, so it will never be displayed.

Third, you don't override `getPreferredSize` in `second`, so the layout managers will have no idea what size the component should be and will simply be assigned `0x0`, making it as good as invisible as makes no difference

Fourth, you're using `null` layouts. This is going to make you life impossibly hard.  Swing has been designed and optimised around the use of layout managers, they do important work in deciding how best to deal with differences in font metrics across different rendering systems/pipelines, I **highly** recommend that you take the time to learn how to use them

Fifthly, `paintComponent` has no business been `public`, no one should ever call it directly

## Example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Sav {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Sav window = new Sav();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Sav() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, gbc);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                second s = new second();
                frame.add(s, gbc);
                frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, gbc);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class second extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private Timer animator;
        private ImageIcon imageArray[];
        private int delay = 50, totalFrames = 8, currentFreames = 1;

        public second() {
            imageArray = new ImageIcon[totalFrames];
            for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
                imageArray[i] = new ImageIcon(getImage(i));

            }
            animator = new Timer(delay, this);
            animator.start();

        }

        protected Image getImage(int index) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            g2d.dispose();
            String text = Integer.toString(index);
            int height = fm.getHeight();
            int width = fm.stringWidth(text);

            img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(getForeground());
            g2d.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
            g2d.dispose();
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(imageArray[0].getIconWidth(), imageArray[1].getIconHeight());
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            imageArray[currentFreames].paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            currentFreames++;
            if (currentFreames >= imageArray.length) {
                currentFreames = 0;
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

> Your code is also not working. It increment the values of image set but do not displays the images

Works just fine for me...

[image: Example]

`imageArray[i]=new ImageIcon(i+1+".png");` will not generate any errors if the image can't be loaded for some reason (and it will load the images in the background thread, which is just another issue).

Instead, I would recommend using `ImageIO.read` instead, which will throw a `IOException` if the image can't be read for some reason, which is infinitely more useful. See [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for going through the code , But after adding also and the changes you suggested it did not work. Can you suggest me something else why it is not working

Comment: I still suspect the `null` layout

Comment: I have used absolute layout.in program  But if layout is null and if you are correct how could i make it correct can you help me ?

Comment: [Laying out components in a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) might be a good place to start

Comment: Your code is also not working. It increment the values of image set but do not displays the images

Comment: The number is increasing that true there is no doubt about it but paint component is not working

Comment: @LakshayGupta If you read my code, you will see I generate a custom icon, which is simply the number of the frame.  I then paint those, just as you code was.  You will need to supply your own icons, as I just didn't have a sequence of 8 icons laying around

Comment: i have supplied the icons but still its not working believe me

Comment: @LakshayGupta Then the issue would seem to be with your icons.  Did you read the update to the answer about `ImageIcon` related issues?

Comment: Yes I read about the update about image icon still it is not working i am not understanding why  it is not working

Comment: @LakshayGupta With the available information, I would say that the images aren't been loaded

Comment: I cannot say the same as this is working fine in another  module but i want to do it in this style to enhance the design  and in this way it is not working

Comment: @MadProgrammer sincerely thankful for your diligence support .

Comment: @LakshayGupta Well, since I can proof the painting process works fine, it's the only piece of the puzzle I can't diagnose, and since it's "not working" for you, I would say it's the area you need to diagnose

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you tell me where you have pass the  address location of images in your given code preciously

Comment: @LakshayGupta I create my images at runtime at the same place you load them - `imageArray[i] = new ImageIcon(getImage(i));` - Not `ImageIcon(String)` assumes that a file (with the specified name) exists on the file system.  Since you're using a relative path (or an absence of one), it is assumed the the file will in the same location that the application is launched from (ie the working directory), which can be different from where the jar file is located

Comment: See I am using eclipse and in eclipse I get to learn that pictures has to be pasted inside the src folder and I did exactly the same thing but the code is not working

Comment: *"See I am using eclipse and in eclipse I get to learn that pictures has to be pasted inside the src folder and I did exactly the same thing but the code is not working"* - Then, if Eclipse is doing the right thing, those images will become embedded resources, which you will no longer be able to access as if they are files. Instead, you will need to use `Class#getResource` to load them.  You will need to know the `package` they are stored in and the relationship between you class's `package` and it

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks a lot for your precious time my code also works fine now and yours too and you were very well right about the layout it was a layout problem . Thanks a lot once again!